# How does std::pair constructor overload taking tuples tell if tuple contents are r-val references?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, rvalue-reference, std-pair, stdtuple

Apologies for the awkwardly worded question. My uncertainty is based on a situation that can roughly be reduced  to the following scenaio.

I have a `Foo` class, and I'd like a `std::pair<int, Foo>` object. `Foo` is defined as follows:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int& a, int& b) { std::cout << "constructor with lvals called\n"; ... }
    Foo(int&& a, int&& b) { std::cout << "constructor with rvals called\n"; ... }
...
};
```

Now if I create my `std::pair` as follows:

```
std::pair<int, Foo> myPair{std::piecewise_construct,
                           std::forward_as_tuple(1),
                           std::forward_as_tuple(2, 3)};
```

[The function signature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) for `std::forward_as_tuple` is

```
template< class... Types >
tuple<Types&&...> forward_as_tuple( Types&&... args )
```

Hence my call to the constructor of `std::pair` should resolve to something like the following:

```
std::pair<int, Foo> myPair{std::piecewise_construct,
                           tuple<int&&>(1),
                           tuple<int&&, int&&>(2, 3)};
```

This will (I imagine) call the [following constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) of std::pair:

```
template< class... Args1, class... Args2 >
constexpr pair( std::piecewise_construct_t,
                std::tuple<Args1...> first_args,
                std::tuple<Args2...> second_args );
```

It looks like this constructor will deduce `Args1` as `(int)` and `Args2` as `(int, int)`, and therefore that `second_args` will bind to a `tuple<int, int>` object copied from the `tuple<int&&, int&&>` argument that was passed to it. However when I run this code I do get
"constructor with r-vals called" printed to screen, so clearly the contents of `second_args` are r-val references, and there's a gap in my understanding. I imagine I might be missing something during the template deduction in `std::pair`'s constructor, but I'm not sure what it is.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: "It looks like this constructor will deduce Args1 as (int) and Args2 as (int, int)" This is the step that's wrong. Args1 is deduced as (int&&) and Args2 is deduced as (int&&,int&&).

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the fact that in the deduction process, references collapse. But, collapsing doesn't affect the types of the tuple elements themselves. So, even though int&& collapses to int during deduction, the actual types in the tuples remain unchanged.

if you do something like this, you will get the lvalue print.

```
int a = 2, b = 3;
std::pair<int, Foo> myPair{std::piecewise_construct,
                           std::forward_as_tuple(1),
                           std::forward_as_tuple(a, b)};
```

This link is very good for template argument deduction. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thanks!